# mvc dropdown on change not firing jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CharacterID")
```

and the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#CharacterID").on(change, "#CharacterID", (function () {
        alert("I've Changed");
        //var id = $('#CharacterID').val();
    }));
});
```

which is not firing when I change one of the dropdown selections.

What can I do to fix this? I've looked at similar questions and answers and tried incorporating those but they haven't worked.

Here's what happens when I try running it in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vgMdF/

Comment: please try my solution, it will work for sure. 
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The `change` is a string, not a magic variable. Add the quotations around it.
2. Also the on method needs to be called on any anscestor of the CharacterID. For most cases, its best to use `$(document).on()`.

.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("change", "#CharacterID", (function () {
        alert("I've Changed");
        //var id = $('#CharacterID').val();
    }));
});
```

You can see this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/h3q5d/

With your full page, and jquery loaded - it also works: http://jsfiddle.net/vgMdF/1/

Comment: I've tried using that code and unfortunately the event still isn't firing.

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: edited to show a jsFiddle example of it working with this code.

Comment: 1.11.1 is what I've been using

Comment: then this answer above should work. if it still doesn't you may wish to verify that the select element does indeed have an `id="CharacterID"` and that no other elements have the same ID

Comment: Right now this is the only control on the view. After running it in debug and checking the source this is what I see `<select id="CharacterID" name="CharacterID">`

Comment: How about putting the full html in a jsfiddle and linking it on your question. as you can see from the jsFiddle in this answer, the code shown should all be correct. The issue likely lies elsewhere

Comment: Are you sure your page is including jquery then..?

Comment: his jsfiddle not ever include jquery

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jQuery in your demo and it should work as expected.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For `jsFiddle`, you can choose jQuery version from `Extensions & Frameworks` tab.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgMdF/3/)**

Comment: @felix his updated fiddle was already added to my answer with jquery loaded, ten hours previously. And that fiddle was just him attempting my answer with the two fixes for his code above applied.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#CharacterID").on('change',function () {
    alert("I've Changed");
    //var id = $('#CharacterID').val();
  });
});
```

Comment: Still no luck it seems

Comment: Are you referencing correctly Jquery? Could you update your question with the full page if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, your jsfiddle not ever include **jquery**, thats y it never run

check this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/qg5Dh/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("change", "#CharacterID", (function () {
        alert("I've Changed");
        //var id = $('#CharacterID').val();
    }));
});
```

it work well and the code work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
$('#CharacterID').change(function(){
        alert("test");
    });
});
```